# MY Sql IN Query in where Clause gives one rows as output

Tags: mysql

This Query returns Only a single row

```
Set @id='2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
Set @typers=1;
Select * from Employee where (@typers=1 and pkEmpId in (@id));
```

If we directly assign 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in IN Query it works i know it is because of "  '  ".

But I m getting the same issue when i pass values as Parameter in procedure

```
call CalculateStandardFinalRun('0','4','1900-01-01 00:00:00','1900-01-01 00:00:00','5','1','2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');
```

How Can i get all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should try this one

```
Select * from Employee where (@typers=1 and FIND_IN_SET(pkEmpId, @id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `@id` item is a string.  You may have well used this syntax

```
  pkEmpId in ('something-or-other')
```

It won't do what you want. Each item in the `in` list must be a separate data item.

Comment: :- i have also tried this before posting the Questing but it gives no records